# Rails: is it possible to share session between two apps with two different databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, session-cookies

I have Rails *app 1*, I want *rails app 2* to authenticate through *Rails app 1*, I wonder if that is possible ?

I'm using devise on both:

The reason behind this is that I have the main network app, which is app 1, and then the nodes of the network which are the other apps, I want all the nodes to be able to authenticate through the main app.

I'm already establishing authentication on each app using 1 main User-table from the main app, but now I just need to figure out how to share the session.

---

I have looked at the following questions, but they are doing it inside the same database, not across apps:

[Rails sessions current practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588241/rails-sessions-current-practices)

[Sharing session across rails apps on different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314155/sharing-session-across-rails-apps-on-different-subdomains)

I want to do exactly what this fellow exactly wants to do:

---

[Rails authentication strategy for noob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387577/rails-authentication-strategy-for-noob)

---

```
Navigate to rails app -->
redirect unauthenticated users to SSO server -->
login and authenticate via remote SSO server -->
callback/redirect to rails app -->
capture user info passed back from SSO server and load protected resources in rails app
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I think I can use this [Rest-Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) to authenticate through rails app 1 on rails app 2. No ? Yea ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of this articles will help you:

http://stderr.timfischbach.de/2013/09/14/rails-4-and-sinatra-session-sharing.html

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-share-a-session-between-sinatra-and-rails

They describe the session sharing between rack based apps (sinatra and rails) but it will also works with two rails apps.

The basic Authentication middleware is the Warden::Manager and you should only have one config.ru for both applications.

Additional hint:
Maybe you could use some other session store than a Database, like memcached, redis, couchbase or anything.